# How to call a specific Python function from a batch file?

Tags: python, batch-file

Let's say I have this simple Python script, named **MyScript.py**:

```
def MyFunction(someInput):
    #Do something with input
```

I would like to write a batch file that specifically calls **MyFunction** from **MyScript** with *someInput*.

Now, I *could* do some Python-foo and add:

```
import sys

def MyFunction(someInput):
    #Do something with input

if __name__ == "__main__":
    eval(sys.argv[1])
```

Then I can use a batch like this:

```
python MyScript.py MyFunction('awesomeInput')
pause
```

But I have a feeling there's a more obvious solution here that doesn't involve me retrofitting **"_*name*_ == "_*main*_"** logic in each of my scripts.

Comment: Create another .py file where you call all the functions from different scripts with the inputs. Include the main function in this new .py file and invoke the new script from the batch file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are in the same folder as the script you can do:

```
python -c "import Myscript;Myscript.MyFunction('SomeInput')"
```

Comment: Great! I ended up adding the following for an absolute path:
python -c "import sys; sys.path.append('C:\My\Absolute\Path'); import MyScript;MyScript.MyFunction('SomeInput')"

Answer (score 2):

Indeed. You can use the `-c` (command) argument.

```
python -c "import MyScript; MyScript.MyFunction('someInput')"
```

Comment: Yeah, looks like I missed ya by a few seconds. :)

Comment: it doesn't even work! I get MyScript is not defined I'm sure that's what i wanted to do to start with

Comment: It was missing the quotes, `"..."`.

Comment: Now its just the same as mine!

Comment: How about this: `python -c "import Noelkd; Noelkd.Answer('Drewness=Fail')"`. Will that work..?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a batch file using this trick:

```
@echo off
rem = """
rem Do any custom setup like setting environment variables etc if required here ...

python -x "%~f0" %*
goto endofPython """

# Your python code goes here ..

from MyScript import MyFunction

MyFunction('awesomeInput')

rem = """
:endofPython """
```

Answer (score 0):

my_function.py:

```
import sys

def MyFunction(someInput):
    print 'MyFunction:', someInput
    #Do something with input

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

you call it from shell with:

```
python -c 'from my_function import MyFunction ; MyFunction("hello")'
```